# Why do the seder on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, passover-seder-hagada, derabanan, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

When Purim that falls out on shabbos we do not  read the Meggila.

When Rosh hashana falls out on shabbos we dont blow shofar.

When Succos is on shabbos we dont shake lulav.

Why? because of Takana Deraba that shema yaavirenu daled amos breshus harabim meaning that we are concerned that he may have a qustion on how to fulfill the mitzva and will carry it on shabbos to the rov.

Why then is Pesach any different? This year Pesach is on shabbos and we will still do the seder.

But hold on: why do we not say that we are worried that he will come to the rov and carry his seder plate to find what to do, or bring his cup of wine to find out if it is the right size and so on and so forth? If any yom tov has the most complicated details it is pesach.

Now please do not answer what you find in the the few achronim like (hemek hamelech) or chemdas yisral or in shoel umashiv that the rov would got to the peoples homes or that the other yomm toivim by learning about the yom tov its like you fulfill the mitzva etc.

Those assumption are clearly a problem for many reasons one being that what they are saying is that really there is a issue of Takana deraba just they would go to the houses etc.
So then that is a massive chidush and you do not find it mentioned any where not in gemara or any rishonim also if we were supposed to learn about the other yomim toivim on that yom yov it should say so in halacha.

Also Please no answers from Kabbala.
 I do not believe there is a good answer from Nigle part of Torah. And there is nothing wrong with that because there is such a concept that Torah has many levels and where one level stops one starts like peshat remez derush and sod where peshat cant answer remez can etc.

It is just so interesting that this question is not spoken about anywhere when it seems as such a simple and obvious question.

Comment: You can also say that since Korban Pesach has an Issur Kareit, we won't apply a Gezera DeRabba to the Seder, and that holds even post-Mikdash. (But this is just Pilpul.)

Comment: See also https://judaism.codidact.com/posts/281339

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, *gezeira d'rabba* seems to be only an issue when there is an irregular *mitzva* involving a specialized skill that requires a certain amount of expertise, and that involves a special, carriable object. There is no *mitzvah*, neither *d'rabanan* nor *d'orayta*, that fulfills this criterion on the *leil seder*, which instead involves retelling the story of the exodus while consuming commemorative food and drink (which would typically have been prepared before Yom Tov).

Comment: lulav takes talent.....you need to do a real skillful lift and shake........:)

Comment: This question is brought up by Achronim(Hemek shaalo-67 siman 21. Shoel Umashiv-madura 4 vol 1 siman 5. Chemdas Yisroel in Hakdoma). If the mitzva was so simple then what was there hava amina to say that since pesach is no simple yom tov the rabbis will go to everyone's home to help them so they wont come to them with all their stuff. Just on eating the matza we have besides the hundreds of halochos Yes on how to eat matza A famous machlokes between chachomim and hillel.

Comment: @menachem You need more skill to know how to shake it than to eat your dinner.............. :)

Comment: @DoubleAA lol ya but lets say you need to eat and drink a certain amount and you dont know how much that is  what will you do sorry not you someone that did not learn the whole shulchan aruch

Comment: @menachem lol ya you just eat the same amount you eat normally at a meal where you Bentch (more than a Kezayit) and drink the same amount you drink at Kiddush. No need to know any Shulchan Arukh at all. Everyone has been Bentching and saying Kiddush their whole life.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Dovid Kviat, author of Succas Dovid on shas, would ask this question in his drashos.

He answered that all the other mitzvos for all other holidays are simply acts which must be  performed at their proper time,  namely that particular holiday. As such Chazzal were able to enact a safekeep to not perform that act without interfering with the actual holiday.

Matzah on Pesach is different. Matzah on Pesach is an integral part of the actual holiday. Chazzal had no intention to diminish the actual holiday by disallowing an act  which is so integral.

Comment: I do not understand.  What he is saying is that really we are worried about shema yavirenu - that he might carry it. Only because it is so integral to Pesach do we not say shema yavirenu . If so then the gemara or at least Rishonim should make note of that. because it is a huge chiddush that we make that exception.       Also why is matza more integral to pesach then megggila is to purim or shofar to rosh hashana.

Comment: @menachem "why is matza more integral to pesach" Read this article to find out http://asif.co.il/?wpfb_dl=1552